# how to build, install, and run curllib in c++

Tags: c++, windows, curl, visual-studio-2015, libcurl

I'm trying to build, install, and run curllib in c++ on Windows 10 but locks up when the run starts.  Here are steps:

1. Download curl-7.59.0.zip from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
2. Extract to c:\opt\curl-7.59.0
3. Start Menu>Visual Studio 2015>Developer Command Prompt for VS2015
4. cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64
5. vcvars64.bat
6. cd c:\opt\curl-7.59.0\winbuild
7. nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=yes
8. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>VC++ Directories>Include Directories, add C:\opt\curl-7.59.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-debug-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include\curl
9. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>C/C++>General/Additional Include Directories, add C:\opt\curl-7.59.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-debug-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include\curl
10. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>Additional Dependencies, add C:\opt\curl-7.59.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-debug-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_debug.lib
11. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>General>Additional Library Dependencies, add C:\opt\curl-7.59.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-debug-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_debug.lib
12. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies, add C:\opt\curl-7.59.0\builds\libcurl-vc14-x64-debug-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_debug.lib
13. Project>Properties>Platform shows Active(x64).  Configuration: shows Active(Debug)
14. In VS2015, Project>Properties>Configuration Properties>C/C++>Preprocessor, add CURL_STATICLIB
15. In VS2015, Build>Clean Solution
16. In VS2015, Build>Rebuild Solution

The program runs but locks up.  No error messages are written to the log file.  In fact, it isn't even touched.  If I comment out this line:

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

Then it will run.  But of course then I don't have any access to curl which is the whole point.

Here is some code:

```
  #include <curl.h>

  vector<string> getDrawingNames(const string &projectName) {
    logFile << "starting getDrawingNames" << endl;
    vector<string> drwNames;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string readBuffer;

    curl = curl_easy_init();   //DOESN'T LIKE THIS LINE
    /*
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        logFile << readBuffer << endl;
    }   
    */
    return drwNames;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. do you want to find out why `unresolved external` here?

Comment: yes, didn't I include enough stuff?

Comment: I'm afraid you might even go too far. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I already had CURL_STATICLIB in the "Preprocessor Definitions" section.

Comment: I edited the post to work with 64bit version of curl.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and examined what the program is doing during the lockup?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that because the program is executed within another application, using its API.  Besides, I shouldn't have to deal with curl_easy_init code.  Its obviously a setup problem.  Hoping someone using curl has run into the same thing and has a solution.

Comment: `curl_easy_init()` should be done somewhere in `main()`, not in this utility function. The documentation warns the function is not thread safe, for example.